# How to take an li and put it into specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery and I'm doing a slider.

I have:

```
<ul>
    <li> <img src="image.jpg"><p>description of the current image</p></li>
    <li> <img src="image.jpg"><p>description of the current image</p></li>
    <li> <img src="image.jpg"><p>description of the current image</p></li>
    <li> <img src="image.jpg"><p>description of the current image</p></li>
</ul>
```

what I need to do is when I click on a specific `<li>` element, it will be displayed in a lightbox with its content.

```
<div id="lightbox">Here is clicked li and its content</div>
```

I don't know really where to start.

How do I tell jQuery to take a `li` and put into `div`?

Comment: A LI element isn't a valid child of a DIV, so I think you'd have to be more specific, do you just want to clone the content ?

Comment: it going to be a gallery.  
and when i click on li a big light is opened with the content

Answer (score 4):

You could do as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        $('#lightbox').html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: You've got a point there, .html will replace the entire content right? I'm removing it :) thanks for the headsup

Comment: I think empty isn't needed too, but answer is right. And as he seems to be very newbie it would be great to show him to put it code on page load... Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks, yes, document ready should be a nice enhancement to the answer, I will add it :)

Comment: yeah i already have $(document).ready() :)

but what if lightbox DIV has a content too. it has a Close X button and NEXT and PREV inputs. 
when i did this
$("#gallery li").click(function(){
   $(".lightbox").fadeIn("slow").html($(this).html()); 
  })
inputs are not displayed for some reason...

Comment: You should narrow the scope of where you are loading the lis HTML,  put a container inside your light box with an Id and instead of replacing the whole light box just replace the content of the container.